# Saving XML Values to Variable Using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to save values from an XML doc into a variable. I am aware you can do the following:

`<xsl:variable name="variableName" select="xml/node/*"/>`

Below is my XML code:

```
<xml>
<graph2>
    <averageHighTemperatures>
        <January>8.3</January>
        <February>8.5</February>
        <March>11.1</March>
        <April>13.5</April>
        <May>17.1</May>
        <June>20.0</June>
        <July>22.6</July>
        <August>22.5</August>
        <September>19.3</September>
        <October>15.3</October>
        <November>11.2</November>
        <December>9.1</December>
    </averageHighTemperatures>
</graph2>
</xml>
```

How can I select the value of each month by specifying the node in the XML doc?

Below is my XSL:

```
    <xsl:variable name="var" select="xml/graph2/averageHighTemperatures/*"/>

    <table>
        <xsl:for-each select="xml/graph2/averageHighTemperatures">
        <tr>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="January $var"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="February $var"/></td>
        </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
```

In the above, "January" and "February" are only being used to present the value wanted.

Comment: What is the result you expect to get?

Comment: So, you are just trying to figure out how to select the specific month from your `$var`? In the example, you are just trying to indicate that you would only want January and February's temps: `<td>8.3</td><td>8.5<td>` ? If so, it would be helpful to add an example of the desired output. Your example XSLT is a little confusing, since it isn't clear whether you want "January" and "February" to appear in the output, or if you are just indicating that is the month's value that you want to be able to select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the month names are the element names, you could select them with a predicate filter matching the `local-name()`:

```
<xsl:transform version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="var" select="xml/graph2/averageHighTemperatures/*"/>

    <table>
        <xsl:for-each select="xml/graph2/averageHighTemperatures">
            <tr>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="'January ', $var[local-name()='January']"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="'February ', $var[local-name()='February']"/></td>
            </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

If you are going to perform multiple lookups, then a better/faster way to select by name would be to use [`xsl:key` and the `key()` function](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/REC-xslt-30-20170608/#key):

```
<xsl:transform version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:key name="var" match="xml/graph2/averageHighTemperatures/*" use="local-name()"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <table>
        <xsl:for-each select="xml/graph2/averageHighTemperatures">
            <tr>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="'January ', key('var', 'January')"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="'February ', key('var', 'February')"/></td>
            </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

Comment: That works perfectly thank you. I do have a question regarding the points in the polyline. The line at the moment looks like a crater with a rather than a mountain. I am aware this is because the Y value is plotted 100 (height) - XML value (8) = 92 which is a greater value than say, 100 - XML value (22) = 78. How can I perform an inversion to have the value of 22 plotted above the lesser XML values?

Comment: The easiest way to invert the numbers is to multiply by -1, or even just add a "-" when generating the output, but it's difficult to advise without more context. Maybe ask in a separate question with more details describing the issue and examples of desired outcome.

Comment: This is weird (for lack of a better word): why are you doing `xsl:for-each` on a **single** node? And why are you **not** doing `xsl:for-each` on the **multiple** child nodes, instead of repeating the code for every one of them?

Comment: That was in the OP original code sample. Just showing how to answer the question without rewriting the whole thing. Not sure if it was being used to set the context node (for shorter XPaths to keep things DRY), if the real data would have multiple averageHighTemperatures elements, etc. Generally, I would replace an `xsl:for-each` with `xsl:apply-templates`.

Comment: @MadsHansen Take a look at OP's last three questions.

Comment: Oh, yes, now that makes sense. @gcpreston I have added an answer to help plot those values in the SVG line chart https://stackoverflow.com/a/54383260/14419